# foundation failure opening a modal at page start

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am opening my foundaiton modal after loading jQuery by calling:

`$('#decisionModalId').foundation('open');`

which gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: We're sorry, 'open' is not an available method for this element.`

How can I load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that even though I was initialization foundation before attempting to open this modal:

`$(document).foundation();`

That the above code wasn't "finished loading" (probably waiting for onready from the document, then it runs).  So the fix for me was to run it like this instead:

```
$(function() { // onready
   $('#decisionModalId').foundation('open');
});
```

It wasn't immediately clear if this is the same as what was suggested here: https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/8482#issuecomment-206819207 (which also discusses a few more fix alternatives, but not this one).

I'm guessing with straight `$('#decisionModalId')...` that it runs immediately instead, which is too early.

I would have added this info to the github ticket but it had been locked.  Thankfully SO doesn't have that problem...

Comment: Hi, this is mentioned in the examples and docs and it is also best practice for jQuery projects. Reviving old resolved issues makes not much sense.

Comment: Yeah that closed github ticket didn't mention it so thought I'd mention it here...reviving old resolved issues with "here's another way to fix it" is counter intuitive but sometimes quite useful to followers, at least in my experience, edited this slightly to clarify that, thanks! :)